# How did Thanos travel from place to place?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos was able to travel through what looked like some sort of worm hole or portal.

What allowed him to do this? And what is the mechanism that enabled him to do it?

Answer (score 7):

Thanos used the Space Stone that he acquired on Thor's spaceship in the beginning of the movie. That Infinity Stone allows him to travel instantly across vast distances.

Comment: The correct grammar is capitalised and the name is "Space Stone" not "space infinity stone" so I have re-edited my changes.

Comment: Welcome to the site @justsomeotherguest - TheLethalCarrot's edits are correct here, in particular *Thor's* not *Thors* is definitely correct.

Comment: And while note referred to as 'Stones' on the Marvel website, 'Space Gem' and 'Infinity' is still capitilised https://www.marvel.com/items/space-gem

Comment: There is a "delete" button on the answer if you really feel like you need to delete this. However, edits that improve a post are not harassment but how this community, site and network works. We build off of each other to create better answers and a repository of knowledge.

Comment: I'm sorry that you feel that you are, but you're not being harrassed. Community editing to fix grammar and punctuation mistakes ("Thors" is incorrect) are part of using the site. If you're not willing to accept that your posts can, and will, be edited by other users, then this probably isn't the site for you.

Comment: Please do not deface your post by editing them in such a way... this is classed as (self) vandalism and will be rolled back.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. You might want to have a quick look at the [FAQ] section on editing, specifically "*Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?*"